# C# use session value if not null shortcut

Tags: c#

Is there was a shorter way in C# of writing the following code:

```
var token = Session["token"];
if(token != null)
{
    if((String)token != "")
    {
        var a = (String)token;
    }
}
```

Is there an equivalent of `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Object.ToString())` for objects that potentially are null without causing an exception?

EDIT: Showing actual code, swapping out variable name for "token" and "a". var a is actually a property reference, but for the sake of helpfulness in future situations, left as var a.

Comment: Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Object)` !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well your code would be much simpler to start with if you removed the redundancy:

```
var value = Session["value"];
if (value != null)
{
    string text = value.ToString();
    if (text != "")
    {
        // Use text
    }
}
```

That's already expressing each logical operation once, which is good.

Alternatively you could use the null-coalescing operator:

```
var text = (Session["value"] ?? "").ToString();
if (text != "")
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @SteveB: Sorry, typo - meant to compare with ""

Comment: `ToString()` could return null if the value of `Session["value"]` is not null and its got a really bad implementation of `ToString()`

Comment: @ConradFrix: At that point the original code would fail too. I'm not catering for that :)

Comment: @JonSkeet An improvement `string text = null; if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((text = Session["value"] ?? "").ToString())) { .... }`

Comment: A tiny bit disappointing that there isn't a one-liner for this without writing a new method, but I'll use the ?? suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Not sure... I'm not terribly keen on side effects like that.

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
var candidate = Convert.ToString(Session["var"]);
if(candidate.Length > 0){
     DoSomething(candidate);

}
```

The [Convert.ToString(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh.aspx) will handle the conversion, whatever the actual type it is, while returning `string.Empty` if the value is `null`.

Comment: That's wrong Convert.ToString(null) = null, your code will throw exception, try to run your code, seem document is not correct

Comment: @CuongLe: the documentations states explicitely this rule > Return Value
Type: System.String
The string representation of value, or String.Empty if value is null.

Answer (score 2):

```
object myObj = Session["value"];
if (myObj != null && myObj.ToString() != string.Empty)
string myStr = myObj.ToString();
```

Comment: if you see why it should not, let me know.

Comment: @Freeman `Session["Value"]` is an object, not a string - wrong type error. Try `Session["Value"] as string`.

Comment: Is it now correct? Besides the fact that i am calling the ToString method twice, in case its not an empty string?

Comment: Couldn't you use `Convert.ToString(Session["value"])` which will return null, rather than throw an exception(?)

Comment: Only use the Convert Class when you can't cast any other way, and if i would like an exception not to be thrown i would use the 'as' keyword.

Comment: @Freeman hmm, I guess I misunderstand the true use of it. On a side note, would you agree that, while correct, your code isn't much better than the OP's with the obvious exception of less nesting (that alone is better!)?

Comment: I guess its a bit better, then the nested version.

Answer (score 2):

Use `as` to cast to `string` to avoid exception:

```
string text = Session["value"] as string;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
{
    var a = text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
string value = Session["value"] as string ?? "";
// no need for an `if`
```

Comment: The result of `Session[]` is an object, so isn't implicitly castable to string, this won't compile. Try `Session[""] as string`.

Comment: Apologies, it is worth noting that `as string` is not semantically the same as `ToString` (what the OP is asking for), so isn't possibly ideal for the solution. `ToString` will work for non-null non-string items.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Then he might want to add `value=value.ToString()`. Also, i'm fairly sure that OP just used this expression `Session["value"].ToString()` although he actually wanted this: `(String)Session["value"]`. Many perople do that. I assume that it also should  show us that there's no null reference possible at this point.

Comment: Agreed on last answer. I'd pseudocoded, so I'll alter to the specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["Value"]) as string)
{
      //do something
}
```

Or

```
var a = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["value"] as string) ? "" : Session["value"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Personally I'd go with @JonSkeet's answer utilising the `??` null coalescing operator with the brackets to resolve the statement to a string before calling `ToString` - single liner.</sub>

Just another pointless option: you can compress this into an extension method, as extension method calls work on null "targets":

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static string SafeToString(this object o)
    {
        if (o != null)
        {
            return o.ToString();
        }

        return "";
    } 
}
```

Then you can call:

```
string a = Session["value"].SafeToString();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
{
    // Handle null or empty strings.
}
```

Not sure if I'd do this myself though, as it can appear odd that a null item method call works - unless that person remembers how extension methods are compiled.

Also, extending `object` can really pollute the type interface of object if you aren't strict with the namespaces.

Comment: Your extension method is behaving exactly like the [Convert.ToString(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh.aspx) method ! That said, I don't like (it's a personal feeling) to be able to call methods on null objects. It could lead to confusion I believe.

Comment: @SteveB Quite possibly, but I'm not going to hunt around for semantic equality! :-) I'll perhaps qualify my answer with "Just another pointless option".